# Strange Problem calling remote service

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new to Grails and Groovy however my problem is a simple but strange one.
I am making calls to a remote web service as follows:

```
    public Boolean addInvites(eventid,sessionkey ){

        String url = this.API_URL+"AddInvites?apikey=${sessionkey}&eventid=${eventid}&userids[]=5&userids[]=23";

        def callurl = new URL(url);
        println callurl;

        def jsonResponse = callurl.getText();
        println jsonResponse;
        def jsonParsedObject = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);

        if(jsonParsedObject){
            println jsonParsedObject;
            if(jsonParsedObject.code == 200){

                return true;
            }
        }
    }



    return false;
```

}

The API_URL here is a "https://api..com/"
Normally making these calls works fine. Json gets returned and parsed. However with the above method, if I add only one userids[]=5  then it works fine but if i add a second one everything hangs after the "println callurl;"

I've checked on the webservice side and the call happens and everything works as expected. If I call it in the browser it works fine. but from the grails web app it simply hangs. I know I'm probably doing something silly here, but I am really stuck. Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the [] characters are supposed to be there?  If you use the following at the end of your query string, it will effectively pass userids=[5,23] to the server:

```
&userids=5&userids=23
```

If the brackets really are necessary, use the URL-escaped values `%5B` and `%5D` for them instead.

Comment: Hey matt, thanks for your answer. Normally I write code in PHP and from what I have read using [] is the correct way to pass an array of params in a GET request. will try encoding though.

Comment: encoding didn't work. Strange thing is the when done the way shown in my code, it does make the call and eveything on the api end works as expected.

Comment: Hmm. Well, if it works in a browser, then I guess that is what the server's expecting. Odd. Do you have `curl` in your dev environment. It's directly available on Linux and MacOS and accessible via Cygwin on Windows. If so, could you trying running the following on your command line and include the output: curl -v <the-webservice-URL>

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should consider the following bug entry:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3921

URL.getText() does not specify a connection timeout.

if you have access to the server logs check if requests from your grails app are actually received (when adding a second userids[] parameter). if this is not the case, you will probably have to use tcpdump or Wireshark in order to debug on TCP level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Andre. Checked server and call is definitely being received. As mentioned the api end does everything as expected. I also made the exact same call from a PHP class and all worked as expected. Strange and confusing :)

Comment: please debug on the client-side using the following code which does sort of how getText internally works: `
def bufferedReader = url.newReader('utf-8')
while (bufferedReader.ready())  {
   println bufferedReader.readLine()
}`. since the web-service is responding properly, it would be interesting whether the data is received on the client-side.